# Netty client uses only one thread

Tags: java, netty, nio

I'm implementing a binary protocol above TCP/IP and using Netty to achieve this. My problem is that the performance is rather poor (600 msg/s). I'm connecting as a client to a server with one connection only. When I investigated running instance with JTop I saw that Netty was using 1 worker thread very heavily and the other 5 worker threads are doing nothing (0% ussage). I was digging on the web and all I found is mention of ExecutionHandler. But why should I use this if those 6 worker threads should be enough. Or am I misunderstanding how Netty uses these threads?

My Netty init code:

```
this.channelFactory = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(this.executors, DaemonExecutors.newCachedDaemonThreadPool(), 1, 6);
this.clientBootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(channelFactory);
this.channelGroupHandler = new ClientChannelGroupHandler(this.channels);
this.clientBootstrap.getPipeline().addLast("ChannelGroupHandler", this.channelGroupHandler);
```

Thanks for any hints
Matous

Comment: Are you saying that you're using a single client to connect to the server? Why would the server use the other threads then, one thread per client you know.

Comment: I'm implementing a client which right now connects with just one connection, in the future there will be much more. I thought that the whole point of using NIO is that one connection can be serviced by multiple threads?

Comment: You've got it completely wrong. NIO allows you to use a **single** thread to service multiple connections.

Comment: Aha, I never really digged too deep into NIO, thanks for poining that out. Do you have any good resource on this that I can read? With regards to threading? Anyway this explains the behaviour that I'm seeing in Netty. Thanks! Can I accept comments somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NIO, or rather the non-blocking version of NIO ("New" I/O) allows you to use a single thread for multiple connections, since the thread doesn't block (hence the name) on the read/write operations. Blocking I/O requires a thread for each connection, as the blocking would prevent you from handling traffic between different connections.

This allows you to perform more efficient communication, since you no longer have thread overhead for one.

A decent tutorial is available [here](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/) (the original Oracle tutorial seems to have vanished from the face of the Google).

Comment: It's true that Netty only uses one boss thread, but it does use multiple worker thread to process the work necessary for those events.

Comment: He only has a single connection. There's not enough work for the other worker threads.

Comment: I have the same setup. I only want one connection (one client - one tcp session) but I need the client not only to send messages but also to receive messages from the server. However when I tune the server to send multiple messages simultaneously only two of them reach the client. I have confirmed that the messages have left the Server (logging&wireshark). Any ideas why the client thread only accepts 2 messages? #netty

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only see one worker thread being used is because you are making only a single connection to the server. Had you made multiple connections, more worker threads would have been used.

If each connection's work is suited for parallelization, then you can implement a handler that uses threads internally, but Netty won't to do that for you.

As for the NIO/OIO distinction, it's true that the idea of NIO is to have one thread handling the events for multiple connections. However, this doesn't mean one thread will handle the all the work. The "single thread" only dispatches work to other (i.e. worker) threads.

Here is an excerpt from the Netty doc:

> How threads work There are two types of threads in a
>   NioServerSocketChannelFactory; one is boss thread and the other is
>   worker thread.
>
> Boss threads Each bound ServerSocketChannel has its own boss thread.
>   For example, if you opened two server ports such as 80 and 443, you
>   will have two boss threads. A boss thread accepts incoming connections
>   until the port is unbound. Once a connection is accepted successfully,
>   the boss thread passes the accepted Channel to one of the worker
>   threads that the NioServerSocketChannelFactory manages.
>
> Worker threads One NioServerSocketChannelFactory can have one or more
>   worker threads. A worker thread performs non-blocking read and write
>   for one or more Channels in a non-blocking mode.

Comment: Thanks for response! From what I'm seeing on the client side, one worker thread handles all the work of my connection. I will make some experiments with more connections once I tweak my server simulator so it is able to accept more then one connection :). But anyway it seems that traffic coming from the client connection is handled always by the same worker/thread (its not distributed). Failed to find any description about this in Netty documentation, but I am happy with the explanation Kayaman pointed out. Will check Netty code to confirm when I have the time.